# Hangfire - get next execution time

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have a reccuring job in Hangfire which is triggered by CronTemplate. I need to get next execution time during the job execution.

I came up with an idea to inject CronTemplate into the job and calculate that date using some of existing libraries based on the template, but I have some design concerns about this solution and I think a solution based on some kind of JobExecutionContext would be better, but so far I couldn't find any way to get it.

Does something similar exist in Hangfire? If so, how can I access it?

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex here is some pseudo code that might just answer your question.

```
private DateTime? GetNextExecutionTime(MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    try
    {
        var job = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().GetRecurringJobs().Single(x => x.Job.Method == methodInfo);
        return job == null ? null : job.NextExecution;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it works. I also modified it to search by `JobId .Single(x => x.Id == jobId);`